# Too high RAM usage on Windows 11 at desk

Tags: memory, windows-11

I've got a problem with my new laptop - I have the feeling that the usage of ram is far too high.

Ram usage:

[image: Ram usage]

As you can see, the usage is constant, and at half of my total ram, but when I look into the programs that use the ram, I don't understand.

processes using ram:

[image: processes using ram]

If I sum the early lines, I can go to 3gb, maybe 4gb of ram, but not 8gb.

Does anyone know how to clear this ghost ram usage?

I tried to update my drivers and to do all update possibles using driverclouds or Windows update, but nothing changed.

For information, my laptop is a Victus 16-s0xxx:

[image: Characteristics]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the cache memory of Windows, which is typically 50% of the RAM but can be more.
This memory is not reserved, and will be used by Windows for other uses,
if it's required.

This is standard behavior in most operating systems, not only in Windows.

So don't worry - your memory is still there and available for use.
You don't need to do anything or install any new software.

This is a classical situation that comes up all the time on our site:
Large memory seems to be used, but looking at the processes there is no
explanation. The best answer is:
If you are not running out of memory, then everything is working correctly.

You may keep an eye on the used memory figures and see if they
increase constantly without you doing anything to cause it,
in case you have a memory leak.
If this (very rare) situation doesn't happen, then no point in worrying.